# Reverse accured income on first balance day?

Tags: accounting

When using the cash method for accounting, pre-paid income and expenses, and accrued income and expenses will not be recorded in the books, except on the last day of the year.

For example, on 12/31 an accrued income of $100 is recorded as a debit against an income account in credit. On the 2/17 the customer pays and $100 is recorded for the bank account in debit against accrued income in credit.

My question is if I can on the first day of the year record $100 in credit for accrued income (thus +-0 the asset account) and $100 in debit for income? Then, when I receive the $100 from the customer, I don't have to think about accrued income. I can just record $100 in debit on the bank account and $100 in credit on the income account.

Answer (score 0):

Accounting is all about identifying cashflow at a specific point in time. While arithmetically it would make sense to record $100 in credit for accrued income and $100 in debit for income, as per the principle of prudence we cannot overestimate profits, the customer may not pay the bill, and the amount would be debited to the bad debts account. Crediting the accrued income and debiting income before receiving payments from the customer would go against International Accounting standards as the payment has not yet been received.

Thus a more accurate portrayal of the accounts to record the accrued income would be to credit the amount to income, and to balance the transaction, a debit entry to accounts receivable, which will then be sent to the statement of financial position as at 31/12 2XXX, in current assets. After the payment has been made on 17/12, accounts receivable will be credited and the income account will be debited under 'bank/cash' depending on the type of payment. The payment is thus balanced and the amount received is shown in the bank as $100. Hope this helps!